# Android Paging Library - loadInitial() and loadAfter() running at the same time without scroll recyclerview

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-paging, android-paging-library

For example :

PagedList.Config.Builder().setInitialLoadSizeHint(25).setPageSize(25).

App loading initialData and load Additional Data at the same time. I have no idea how to fix it.

Logs from console:

`D/OkHttp: --> GET https://api.github.com/users/google/repos?page=0&per_page=25`
`D/OkHttp: --> GET https://api.github.com/users/google/repos?page=25&per_page=25`

Comment: Will you prove DataSourceClass code?